# Generated Docx File is Corrupt - C#

Tags: c#, download, response, mime-types, docx

I am creating a docx file with my app, and I get stuck with the `Response.End()`. I get this error:

> Thread was being aborted

I get this error, but the file is still created anyway. When I try to open the file it's always corrupted. I am not having any success writing the `.docx` file. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=utf-8";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "mydoc.docx"));
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ourString);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Please provide executable code.

Answer (score 2):

Note, you should not place `Response.End` inside the try-catch block because it's expected that it will throw that exception.
See the [HttpResponse.End](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.end) method's remarks:

> To mimic the behavior of the End method in ASP, this method tries to
> raise a ThreadAbortException exception.

You can avoid this by using the following:

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=mydoc.docx");
response.OutputStream.Write(ourString, 0, ourString.Length);
response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Note, in the above code I'm presuming that your `ourString` variable is byte array because you were passing it to the `BinaryWrite` method in your snippet code.

However, this name leads me to believe that you have just converted your `string` to `byte[]`, is that correct?

If it is, note that this is not a valid DOCX file, DOCX format is not a plain text, you need to write it correctly using Office Open XML format (WordprocessingML).